# how do i make views clickable through in react native

Tags: react-native, rotation, pan

I have multiple buttons structured like this:

```
<View style={ { height: '100%', width: '10%', transform: rotate } }> // being transformed by rotation inside panResponder
   <View {panresponder}/> // takes the touch event
   <Image/> 
</View>
```

**The Problem**

If there are two cursors 180 degrees away from eachother, the tail end of the encapsulating View will take the touch that was meant for the touchable view of the other.

**The Aim**

I want to be able to click the touchable view at any time even if it is being overlapped by a View. how do i make a View clickable through? Is there a way to layer zIndex that it would make the clickable view rise above other views?(ive been fiddling with zIndex and it makes the components disappear).

Comment: You can use a `TouchableOpacity`, `TouchableNoFeedback`, etc.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={}> or <TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={}>
```

to make anything clickable

Comment: <Pressable> is a better option now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this,

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} underlayColor={"COLOR"} style = {styles.button} onPress = {() => this.onClickView()}>
   <View />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Did not get it @Andrew. You will have to wrap your View inside TouchableHighlight or Opacity etc.

Comment: I figured out a different way to solve my problem using pointerEvents={'box-none'} on my container View and wrapped the image in a View and gave it pointerEvents={'none'}.

Comment: @PratikS.Gode both `TouchableHighlight` & `TouchableOpacity` makes your `View` clickable. `TouchableHighlight` will allow you to add a highlight color on the view when it is pressed. `TouchableOpacity` will dim the opacity of the view when pressed.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

```
<View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => {console.log('Clicked')}}></View>
```

Comment: This is a great solution as well when you don't want touchable to affect other HOC gestures.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the view component inside one of the react native buttons like TouchableHeighlight and provide the event onPress.

`TouchableHeightlight onPress = your event View open View close TouchableHeighlight close`